# Laravel 5.8 - Cannot add or update a child row using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a simple table with multiple data which looks like this:

## Pages table

[image]

I have created a relationship to a table named `prebids` like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('prebids', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('bidder_name');
        $table->string('params_name');
        $table->string('params_value');
        $table->bigInteger('page_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('page_id')->references('id')->on('pages')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Here is the page model:

```
class Page extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        "title",
        "articles",
        "status"
    ];

    public function prebids() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Prebid');
    }
}
```

Here is the prebids model:

```
class Prebid extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        "params_name",
        "params_value",
        "bidder_name"
    ];
    public function page()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Page');
    }
}
```

Now when the user clicks add prebids, I want to store the prebids data as per the model.

So on `pages index.blade.php` on add button I have this

```
<td>
    <a href="{{ route('prebids.create'), $page->id}}"
       class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add prebid</a>
```

And on `prebid controller` I have the following:

```
class PrebidController extends Controller
{

    public function create()
    {
        $prebid = Prebid::all();
        $page = Page::all();

        return view('prebids.create', ['page' => $page]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        foreach ($request->input() as $parameters) {
            $parameters = new prebid();
            $parameters->save();
        }
        return redirect("/pages")->with("sucess", "data successfully saved");
    }

}
```

Now when the user clicks add prebids it opens a form in which user can add information and submit, when I submit I get the followingg error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`royalad`.`prebids`, CONSTRAINT `prebids_page_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`page_id`) REFERENCES `pages` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `prebids` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2019-11-06 15:24:34, 2019-11-06 15:24:34))

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: *"a foreign key constraint fails (royalad.prebids, CONSTRAINT prebids_page_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (page_id) REFERENCES pages(id) ON DELETE CASCADE)"* ... -> `insert into prebids (updated_at, created_at) values (2019-11-06 15:24:34, 2019-11-06 15:24:34)`  ... From what i see the foreign key is never used in the insert ... @DevsiOdedra

Comment: @RaymondNijland so what do I need to change to solve my problem?

Comment: Where is your form code? Please post your form code..

Comment: Btw, why you're `foreach`-ing the `$request->input()`? You're doing wrong. It will create `prebid` as many as your input values.

Comment: Then, what is this `{{ route('prebids.create'), $page->id}}`? It's wrong syntax, it's should throwing an error actually..

Comment: I want to get the page ID in which the user clicked the add prebid button

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate a page to your model before saving it:

```php
$parameters = new prebid();
$parameters->page()->associate( $theActualPageObject )
$parameters->save();
```

Otherwise, the column `page_id` in your `prebid` table would be empty, which is not allowed since you set up a relationship to `pages.id` there - hence the foreign key constraint error.

If you don't always have a page, you can also make the `page_id` `nullable` and default it to `null`

```php
$table->bigInteger('page_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
```

Comment: The `Page` object you want to associate with. You need to load this one yourself, since I don't know which page you wan't to associate to your prebid. Likely you need to add the page_id as parameter to your form.

Comment: I want to associate with page ID   in which the add prebid button was clicked

Comment: Well, pass the page id to your form and further to the store method then

Comment: How do I pass page id to the form?  I tried this `{{ route('prebids.create'), $page->id}}` but its not working

Comment: You have to put the parameter inside the route function: `{{ route('prebids.create', ['id' => $page->id]) }}`. See the documentation for details: https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-route